# Specify multiple widgets in slidify

Tags: r, knitr, mathjax, slidify

How can I specify two widgets in a slidify RMarkdown document? Given the following example:

```
---
title       : Test
subtitle    : 
author      : 
job         : 
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : {mathjax, quiz} # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
---

## A fraction:

$\frac{1}{0}$

---&radio .quiz

## A quiz:

A or B?

1. A
2. _B_
```

I can't seem to get both the quiz and mathjax to be loaded. I've tried a few sample separators such as omitting the curly braces, a space, multiple widget statements, but I haven't managed to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to get multiple widgets in would be to use square brackets. Your widget line should read:

```
widgets     : [mathjax, quiz]
```

The documentation for slidify is still a little sparse, so a good source of answers is [this repository](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyExamples/tree/gh-pages/examples/io2012) by the author which has some very good examples.

Comment: All front-matter in slide.Rmd must be valid YAML. Widgets are specified as an array of widget names, which uses square brackets.

Comment: @Ramnath May I make a small suggestion? In the commented out options, you have them in curly brackets. I think if you make them square brackets, it might be more intuitive to those who aren't really experienced in this area at no detriment in quality to the package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will make the changes when I push the next version.